# For processes to be up and running all the time

Tags: cron, upstart, init

I want my python program **sample.py** to be always up and running. I have read some things and asked people about ways to do this. So far I have following options -

- Upstart
- Cron

I am trying things with *upstart* right now. I have created a **sample.conf** in `$HOME/.init/`.

```
#sample.conf
description "gearmanWorker1"
author "hussain"
pre-start script
  logger "pre-start for sample"
end script

post-start script
  logger "post-start for sample"
end script

script
  logger "just before executing sample.sh"
  exec /usr/bin/python /home/magic/Documents/gearman-python/Worker.py
end script
```

But when I do `sudo initctl start sample` / `sudo start sample` it says -

```
start: Unknown job: sample
```

When I do `status sample`, it says -

```
sample stop/waiting
```

which means sample process is not running yet.
I don't know if I am doing this right; I am very new to this. Also I don't think cron will be the best way to achieve what I want. Because I just want to monitor **sample** in such a way that it will automatically restart after a failure/abort. It should also restart after a reboot.

Also feel free to suggest any other better ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Put the script in `/etc/init` or read cookbook section about enabling user jobs: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#id96